# Why does Beautiful soup add extra xml declaration to the document and how to remove it?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I trying to parse a simple xml that has a header. Here is the code:

```
str(BeautifulSoup("""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data/>
""", features='xml'))
```

output is fillowing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><data/>
```

As one can see, there is and extra header and it also has incorrect format. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

versions:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
lxml==3.4.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `xml` to the `features`parameter, `lxml` builds the xml tree itself. So you don't need to put the header yourself.

```
>>> str(BeautifulSoup("""
... <data/>
... """, features='xml'))
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<data/>'

>>>
```

Comment: In my app, xml already has a header. Is there an effective way to remove it automatically? Or tell BeautifulSoup to ignore it?

Comment: I do not know of any. I have to search.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Short answer Yes, you are doing it wrong.

## How?

The reason you are getting two XML declaration is because you pass in the `features` argument which Beautiful Soup uses to [build the tree](https://github.com/JinnLynn/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py#L142).

```
if builder is None:
    if isinstance(features, basestring):
        features = [features]
    if features is None or len(features) == 0:
        features = self.DEFAULT_BUILDER_FEATURES
    builder_class = builder_registry.lookup(*features)
    if builder_class is None:
    raise FeatureNotFound(
            "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you "
            "requested: %s. Do you need to install a parser library?"
            % ",".join(features))
    builder = builder_class()
self.builder = builder
self.is_xml = builder.is_xml
self.builder.soup = self
```

But that is not all the history. The `self.is_xml` is used in the the [`.decode()`](https://github.com/JinnLynn/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py#L345) which returns a string or Unicode representation of the document and when `self.is_xml` is truthy it [adds an XML declaration to the tree.](https://github.com/JinnLynn/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py#L351)

```
if self.is_xml:
    # Print the XML declaration
    encoding_part = ''
    if eventual_encoding != None:
        encoding_part = ' encoding="%s"' % eventual_encoding
    prefix = u'<?xml version="1.0"%s?>\n' % encoding_part
    ...
```

So finally you will end up with two *XML declarations*.

## How To fix this?

You need to pass in your parser which is 'xml' as the second argument to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor as mentioned in [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
... <data/>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'xml')
>>> str(soup)
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<data/>'
```

Comment: and to remove the xml header from the string (last line above), something like `str(soup).split("\n")[-1]`